# Kentico 10 Order by Expression

Tags: filter, kentico

I am trying to come up with an Order by expression conditional that will work for what we need.

I need to be able to order the most recent update/modified.

I am doing it with another set of data that has a posting date by doing

```
BlogPostDate DESC
```

The data I am filtering off doesn't have a field like this. Does Kentico have an order by clause like NodeLevel, NodeOrder, NodeName but for most recently updated?

Comment: When you say "The data I am filtering off doesn't have a field like this" are you building a custom filter or what are you doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DocumentModifiedWhen` which is a DateTime property of the TreeNode class.

https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/P_CMS_DocumentEngine_TreeNode_DocumentModifiedWhen.htm